# SQL subquery and Joins giving same or different result (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I'm working to optimize queries due to huge amount of data on Oracle.

There is one query like this.

With subquery :

```
SELECT
  STG.ID1,
  STG.ID2
FROM (SELECT 
        DISTINCT
        H1.ID1,
        H2.ID2
      FROM T_STGDV STG
      INNER JOIN T_HUB1 H1 ON STG.BK1 = H1.BK1
      INNER JOIN T_HUB2 H2 ON STG.BK2 = H2.BK2 ) STG
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_LINK L ON  L.ID1 = STG.ID1 AND L.ID2 = STG.ID2
WHERE L.IDL IS NULL;
```

I'm doing this optimization :

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  H1.ID1,
  H2.ID2
FROM T_STGDV STG
INNER JOIN T_HUB1 H1 ON STG.BK1 = H1.BK1
INNER JOIN T_HUB2 H2 ON STG.BK2 = H2.BK2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_LINK L ON L.ID1 = H1.ID1 AND L.ID2 = H2.ID2
WHERE L.IDL IS NULL;
```

I want to know if the result will be the same, the behavior is the same.

I did some tests, I didn't find difference but maybe i missed some test case ?

Any idea what could be the difference between those queries ?

Thanks.

Some details, the Explain plan for those testing tables (the cost are not representative of the real tables)

**the First query :**

```
Plan hash value: 2680307749

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |         |     1 |    65 |    11  (28)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                 |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER       |         |     1 |    65 |    11  (28)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW                 |         |     1 |    26 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     HASH UNIQUE         |         |     1 |   134 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN          |         |     1 |   134 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN         |         |     1 |    94 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_STGDV |     1 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_HUB1  |     2 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL | T_HUB2  |     2 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | T_LINK  |     3 |   117 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("L"."IDL" IS NULL)
   2 - access("L"."ID2"(+)="STG"."ID2" AND "L"."ID1"(+)="STG"."ID1")
   5 - access("STG"."BK2"="H2"."BK2")
   6 - access("STG"."BK1"="H1"."BK1")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

**the second query**

```
Plan hash value: 2149614538

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |         |     1 |    65 |    11  (28)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE            |         |     1 |    65 |    11  (28)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   FILTER                |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER      |         |     1 |    65 |    10  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW                |         |     1 |    26 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN          |         |     1 |   134 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN         |         |     1 |    94 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_STGDV |     1 |    54 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_HUB1  |     2 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL | T_HUB2  |     2 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | T_LINK  |     3 |   117 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("L"."IDL" IS NULL)
   3 - access("L"."ID2"(+)="H2"."ID2" AND "L"."ID1"(+)="H1"."ID1")
   5 - access("STG"."BK2"="H2"."BK2")
   6 - access("STG"."BK1"="H1"."BK1")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: They look similar to me. My advice is to compare their execution plans. I'd expect them to be similar, but who knows.

Comment: Yes there are quite similar ... especially the order where the join are executed. But the 2nd query is 20x faster...

Answer (score 0):

The queries look equivalent to me, because of the `where` clause.

Without the `where` clause they are not equivalent.  Duplicates in `t_link` (relative to the `join` keys) would result in duplicate rows.  However, you are looking for no matches, so this is not an issue.  When there is no match, the two versions should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test them with your current dataset you can use minus.

query 1
MINUS
query 2

If any results are displayed, they are not the same.

You have to flip them around to try the other way too...

query 2
MINUS
query 1

If both tests return no records, the queries have the same effect on your current dataset.

Comment: I did the test with minus, but i don't want to miss any test case ... All my minus test are empty but ... maybe one case would not work ...

Comment: If T_LINK.ID1 and T_LINK.ID2 are unique, you shouldn't have an issue. If you have two records in T_LINK with the same ID1 and ID2, and IDL is null on both, the first query would show the the same ID1 and ID2 two times since the distinct is in the sub-query and not in the main select as it is in your second query, so your second one would only return one record.

Comment: Yes, my target T_LINK has a unique index on ID1 and ID2.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the difference: look at these lines in your execution plans:

```
2 - access("L"."ID2"(+)="STG"."ID2" AND "L"."ID1"(+)="STG"."ID1")
```

and

```
3 - access("L"."ID2"(+)="H2"."ID2" AND "L"."ID1"(+)="H1"."ID1")
```

`STG` is a temporary table created by Oracle for the duration of the query (that ambiguousness between `T_STGDV` alias and the subquery alias was alone a reason to rewrite the query). And this temporary table is of course unindexed. After your refactoring, Oracle optimiser start joining `T_LINK` with `H1` and `H2` instead of a temporary table and that allows it to utilize indexes built on those table, thus giving you the 20x increase in speed.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, there are giving the same result. And the second one is more efficient.